# Matlab Correlation Coefficient Equivalent function in java

Tags: java, matlab, math

Is there a function equivalent to Matlab's 2-d correlation coefficient? I would like to use it on 2 1-d arrays. 
http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/corr2.html

Edit: My own implementation

```
//Assume we have the length and averages of both arrays
//double a_average, b_average
double a_val =0;
double b_val = 0;
double a_sum = 0 ;
double b_sum = 0;
double a_stdev = 0;
double b_stdev  = 0;
int size = a.length; // same as b's length
for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; i ++) {
    a_val =(a[i]- a_average);
    b_val =(b[i] -b_average);
    a_sum += a_val;
    b_sum += b_val;
    a_stdev += Math.pow(a_val,2);
    b_stdev += Math.pow(b_val,2);
}

double coefficient = ((a_sum *b_sum)/(a_stdev*b_stdev))
```

Thanks

Comment: The link gives you the formula: namely the covariance divided by the product of the standard deviations. What's holding you back?

Comment: I'm actually not too familiar with these formulas and what they mean. I was just told to convert the code from matlab to java. Is this the same thing? http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/correlation/PearsonsCorrelation.html . It seems like matlab doesn't take into consideration the N-1 correction factor?

Comment: Essentially, yes, except that you're taking the sums of products of all the elements of the matrices. Try coding up pieces of the formula and come back if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all of your data is already loaded into two arrays `A and B`, what you want to do is the following.  Also, assume your two arrays are of equal length and are free of NaN and Infinity values.

Also, since you have only two data points, your correlation matrix only contains one off-diagonal value, so I am going to store it as a single double value.

```
int i;
int len = A.length;
double correlation;
double XX = 0; //normally would be an outer-product matrix
double[] runningSum = new double[2]; //since you have two variables (A and B)
double[] x2 = new double[2];
double[] stdev = new double[2];

for (i = 0; i < length; ++i)
{
   XX += A[i] * B[i];
   x2[0] += Math.Pow(A[i], 2.0);
   x2[1] += Math.Pow(B[i], 2.0);
   runningSum[0] += A[i];
   runningSum[1] += B[i];
}

// Compute mu
runningSum[0] = runningSum[0] / len;
runningSum[1] = runningSum[1] / len;

// Compute std deviation (bias-corrected)
stdev[0] = Math.Sqrt(x2[0] - len * Math.Pow(runningSum[0], 2)) / (len - 1);
stdev[1] = Math.Sqrt(x2[1] - len * Math.Pow(runningSum[1], 2)) / (len - 1);

// now compute correlation coefficient
correlation = (XX - (len * runningSum[0] * runningSum[1])) / (nobs - 1);
correlation = correlation / (stdev[0] * stdev[1]);
```

This should give you the answer you are looking for.